# How do I create a XML File from an URL

Tags: java, file, url

For a project I need to parse a XML file. The parsing in itself works with a File but I need to retrieve the file from an URL. How do I save the information from the URL to a file?

I already tried many of the answers provided here but since now none worked the way I would like them to. One of the answer I tried was the following:

```
public File createFile(URL url){
    File f;
    try {
      f = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
      f = new File(url.getPath());
    }
    return f;
}
```

Sadly this does not solve the problem but rather tells me that "URI scheme is not "file""

If anyone could help me with my problem I would be very thankful.

Comment: Do you want to download the content of a URL which is a XML file? Or is it a normal web page?

Comment: the url leads to an xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java IO, this will save it to a target.xml file:

```
public File createFile(URL url) throws IOException {

    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\my-user\\Desktop\\target.xml");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        outStream.write(inputLine.getBytes());
    }

    outStream.close();
    in.close();

    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library to fetch the content of your URL, you can do it with just one line:

```
IOUtils.toString(new URL("YOUR_URL_IN_HERE"), "UTF-8");
```

This will transform the content of your URL into a `String`, you can then write the content to a file or handle the content in any other stream you want.

Here you can find the [docs of IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(byte[],%20java.lang.String))